# How can I get the values of all sibling input checkboxes in a child component?

Tags: reactjs

I have a parent and a child component (Child1) with another child component (Child2). Child2 has checkboxes:

```
    <input name='val1' id='val1' value='val1' type='checkbox' />
    <input name='val2' id='val2' value='val2' type='checkbox' />
```

I want the parent component to be able to get the values of all the checkboxes (probably comma separated). I either want to pass down a handler or have my parent component be able to read all the values

Comment: Passing down the handler is the right way to go.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways to achieve this, but the simplest would be something like this:

```
class Child2 extends React.Component {

  onChangeCheckbox(event) {

    // Update state of child2 to capture current check state of checkbox 
    // inputs in Child2
    this.setState({
      [ event.target.name ] : event.target.checked
    }, () => {    

      // Upload the combined/current state of checkbox name/checked pairs 
      // to Parent via onInputClicked callback prop
      this.props.onInputClicked(this.state)
    })

  }

  render() {

    return (<React.Fragment>
      <input name='val1' id='val1' value='val1' type='checkbox'
      onClick={ event => this.onChangeCheckbox(event) } />
      <input name='val2' id='val2' value='val2' type='checkbox'  
      onClick={ event => this.onChangeCheckbox(event) } />
      </React.Fragment>)
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  render() {

    // Render Child2 with checkbox inputs from Parent and pass onInputClicked
    // prop as a callback
    return (<Child2 onInputClicked={ values => {
      console.log('checkbox values in parent', values)
    } } />)
  }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: What if Child2 were stateless?

Comment: In that case, you could call the `props.onInputClicked` callback directly from the checkbox's `onClick` handler and resolve the values in `<Parent />` - would you like me to revise the answer to demonstrate that?

Comment: Nope, got it! I thought that was the best way, but wasn't sure.